# How do I name a column as a date value in oracle?

Tags: oracle

How do I name a column as a date value ?
 I want to do it with an Oracle query
also when ever i run the query it has to display next 4 dates as a column name

Comment: Please show us some code to see what you've tried so. Also see [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on "How do I ask a good question?".

Comment: Presumably you mean dynamically, so you can't hard-code it as kordirko showed?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically named columns are almost certainly best handled by the application.  Or a PL/SQL block that prints out a query with the correct column names.

If this *must* be done in a single SQL statement you can use my open source project [Method4](https://github.com/jonheller1/method4).  It allows running dynamic SQL in SQL, but it is slow and difficult to use.

Here's an example:

```
select * from table(method4.dynamic_query(
    q'[
        select 
            '
                select 1 a
                    , 2 "'||to_char(sysdate+1, 'YYYY-MM-DD')||'"
                    , 3 "'||to_char(sysdate+2, 'YYYY-MM-DD')||'"
                    , 4 "'||to_char(sysdate+3, 'YYYY-MM-DD')||'"
                    , 5 "'||to_char(sysdate+4, 'YYYY-MM-DD')||'"
                from dual
            '
        from dual
    ]'
));

         A 2016-06-13 2016-06-14 2016-06-15 2016-06-16
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3          4          5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `AS` keyword together with quotes:

```
SELECT some_column As "2015-12-14 14:34:22" FROM table
```